# Ajax not calling controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Ajax. i am trying to call my controller method but call from Ajax not invoking url i am given.. here my controller method and ajax call in my jsp file..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getdata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String add(@RequestParam(value="userDetailObject", required=true) User_Details u,Model model) {
    System.out.println("In the controller method..");
    String result=null;
                result="From controller :"+u.getEmail();
                System.out.println("at controller .."+result);
    return result;
}
```

and my Ajax is

```
//script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.4.4.js"

var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

        function getData() {
            alert("hello");
            // get the form values
        var email = $('#email').val();
        //  var education = $('#education').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url : "/SpringDemoSts/getdata",
                data : 'email=' + email,
                success : function(response) {
                    // we have the response
                    //$('#info').html(response);
                    $('#email').val(response);
                    //$('#education').val('');
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    alert('Error: ' + e);
                }
            });
        }
/script
```

what is wrong i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

the url defined in ajax :

```
/SpringDemoSts/getdata
```

is didfferent to that in the requestmapping shown

```
/getdata
```

and the parameter is called userDetailObject and your ajax call defines data incorrectly,you are using request parameters style as the data. When in fact you need json/a plain primitive or string.

Comment: i also changed my url as   url : "/getdata",

Comment: I don't if thats he correct requetsmapping, you can define mappings at a class level too. Your data is not mapping to paraemter correctly I imagine, you a re trying to create user_object, from email only. That won;t work.

Comment: thanks for reply, i access my web application using http://localhost:8080/SpringDemoSts/get    and i changed controller method declaration..  public @ResponseBody String add(@RequestParam(value="email", required=true) String email,Model model)